# display a sql query being generated

Tags: sql

Im trying to learn how to join two tables using [this tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento) but I'm returning a sql error. In order to work what ive done wrong I would like to see the query being generated, how do I display it?

I've tried `Zend_Debug::dump($collection);` that doesn't gice me the query, what does?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
echo $collection->getSelect();
```

The collection's query is handled by it's select object, and `echo` casts it to a string which renders nicely as SQL.  In some situations you need to cast it manually, e.g.

```
Mage::log((string) $collection->getSelect());
```

Comment: This is the preferred method.

Comment: could more context be provided around how to use this? an example maybe

Comment: @ahnbizcad I'd like to but as long as the collection is a `Varien_Data_Collection_Db` type this should work, and almost all collections in Magento are.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the used query by using `$collection->load(true)` , this will enable the `$collection->printLogQuery(true,true)` (See `Varien_Data_Collection_Db::load()`) and print the used query to both your brwoser as well as log it to the system.log.