# Magento 1.9 - how to display Magento query as a SQL string?

Tags: magento-1.9, sql, querystring

It works beautifully if I'm trying to get collection but it won't for single product by SKU.
for example:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_sku);
    echo $test =  $product->getSelect()->__toString();
```

How can I get sql for a single product can I?
or I must get collection with filter by sku then getSelect()....

... after a quick research ...

```
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED))
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku',$_sku);
```

it does the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`load()` (or `loadByAttribute()`) would execute the query already - so you'll have to catch the query before it is executed. As you say, for example by using `->getSelect()->__toString()` on your `getCollection()`.

Some references on this topic:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840046/magento-how-to-get-sql-query-of-product-load
- [display a sql query being generated](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9464/display-a-sql-query-being-generated)